# Как подключить Method Profiling?

Tags: java, android

Хочу подключить `Method Profiling`, чтоб посмотреть на время выполнения методов, но не могу подключиться к `Method Profiling`.

Посмотрел как в туториалах это делают и на этапе выбора приложения (насколько я понял нужно выбрать пакет с приложение которое нужно протестировать) у меня проблема

Согласно туториала это должно выглядить вот так

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А у меня это выглядит вот так

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Почему у меня не отображается структура?

Comment: а приложение у вас debuggable?

Comment: @metalurgus да точно проблема была в этом. Спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

Нужно было сделать приложение debuggable

Для этого добавил в градл такое

```
android {

//...

buildTypes {
    debug {
        debuggable true
    }
    customDebuggableBuildType {
        debuggable true
    }
    release {
        debuggable false
    }
}

  //...

}
```